# How add google map for sobipro in joomla

Tags: google-maps, joomla

I am creating a website using Joomla version 3.6.4 Stable.

I added a plugin called "SobiPro".

How to add google map for that plugin?

Comment: https://www.sigsiu.net/center/applications

Comment: I added SobiPro. After that how to add google map for this ?